# Postgres combine 2 columns and use group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have pat_first_name and pat_last_name columns in my psql database col. Id like to pick out most common names. I can do first names using

```
SELECT pat_first_name,count(pat_first_name) 
from patients 
GROUP BY pat_first_name 
ORDER BY count DESC;`
```

However, when I try combine it fails

```
SELECT pat_first_name,pat_last_name,count((pat_first_name || ' ' || pat_last_name)) 
from patients 
GROUP BY (pat_first_name || ' ' || pat_last_name) 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

column "patients.pat_first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
SELECT pat_first_name,pat_last_name,COUNT(*) 
FROM patients 
GROUP BY pat_first_name,pat_last_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Or, if you really want the first_name and last_name concatenated in the result:

```
SELECT pat_first_name || ' ' || pat_last_name,COUNT(*) 
FROM patients 
GROUP BY pat_first_name || ' ' || pat_last_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Either way, you gotta have the same "non-count" columns in the SELECT as in the GROUP BY.